# Positive Cartan integers in $A_2$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems

It is well known that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are a set of simple roots for the root system of type $A_2$ and if the angle between them is $\frac{\pi}{3}$, then the Cartan integers $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle = \langle \beta, \alpha \rangle = 1$. How does this agree with the fact that every couple of elements $\alpha_i, \alpha_j$ belonging to a base of a root system must be such that $(\alpha_i, \alpha_j) \leq 0$?

I came up with this question by looking at the Cartan matrix and the associated 2-dimensional representation of $A_2$, where of course the angle between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is obtuse. Why do the non-diagonal entries of the matrix always have to be negative? In other words, is it because the scalar product between two basis elements must be negative or because it is just a standard form?

Comment: "the" generators of a root system ... You mean *a* set of simple roots.

Comment: Or you don't, because for such a set of simple roots, the angle between them is $2\pi/3$, and the Cartan integers to such a pair are both $= -1$. Two roots with an angle of $\pi/3$ between them might still be generators of the root lattice and the ambient vector space, but they are not a basis of the root system = set of simple roots for a chosen positive cone.

Comment: I meant a set of simple roots, I just edited.

Comment: Well but two simple roots in $A_2$ enclose an angle of $2\pi/3$, not $\pi/3$, and then the question disappears.

Comment: Ok, I got it now: if the angle between two simple roots was $\pi/3$ then not every root would be a combination of simple roots with coefficients of the same sign. Sorry for the silly question and thank you.